# drupal..how to modify the style of the login or register shown in content

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-comments

I have a wierd problem that I can't seem to find the solution, probably it is very simple.
the text is this:
Login or register to add comments

```
    <span>
<a href="/user/login?destination=node%2F1179%23comment-form">Login</a> or 
<a href="/user/register?destination=node%2F1179%23comment-form">register</a>
 to add comments
</span>
```

I want to customize this and add some classes for the links in order to personalize it

Comment: If memory serves me right, you should be able to edit the comment form by adding a `themename_comment_form($form)` function in your template.php file and altering the form attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override [theme_comment_post_forbidden](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/theme_comment_post_forbidden/6). To do that, in your theme (say it's called "example"), copy the code in the function that Drupal provides and make the appropriate changes.

```
function example_comment_post_forbidden() {
...
return t('<a class="login-link" href="@login">Login</a> or <a class="register-link"
href="@register">register</a> to post comments', array('@login' => url('user/login', 
array('query' => $destination)), '@register' => url('user/register', array('query' => 
$destination))));
...
}
```

Notice that I added a class attribute to each a element. Again, make sure you copy all the code and make changes only where you need to. Clear the cache to make sure Drupal registers the theme function.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add class if you can match these links using css selector.
For example, with drupal 7 and default theme, you can use :

```
.comment_forbidden a
```

Comment: I have drupal 6 and I need 2 different styles in both <A>

Answer (score 0):

redeclare that form using hook_form_alter and add some attributes to those fields.